# React Native Maps - How to limit panning area?

Tags: android, google-maps, react-native, react-native-maps

[image]

In my above Map, I want to limit the panning when the centre point of the purple circle touches the edge of the screen.

I found this solution, but I'm not able to figure out how to find the bounds of the map (which in android is something like - `map.getBounds()`).

[React-native-maps limit panning area](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49923304/react-native-maps-limit-panning-area)

Also, I did try the below solution to check when the circle's center touches the edge of screen but this didn't work.

```
  _onPanDrag(e) {

     if( JSON.stringify(e.nativeEvent.coordinate.latitude) > this.state.latitude &&
         JSON.stringify(e.nativeEvent.coordinate.longitude) > this.state.longitude ){
                console.log("Crossed!");
        }
    }

<MapView 
    onPanDrag={(e) => this._onPanDrag(e)} 
/>
```